# What does method handleAttribute(String name, Object value) inside UIComponent Mojarra is doing?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

So let pick a UIComponent like `HtmlSelectOneRadio`(Please view source here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.7/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlSelectOneRadio.java#HtmlSelectOneRadio)

So some of the setters will call method `handleAttribute(...)`, and some does not, for example

```
public void setDir(java.lang.String dir) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.dir, dir);
    handleAttribute("dir", dir);
}

public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.disabled, disabled);
}
```

and it is very UNCLEAR to me what `handleAttribute` is doing, can a JSF guru please explain to me what this method try accomplish and why somes attribute call this method while other does not? Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's related to Mojarra-internal rendering optimizations, wherein **only** the attributes which are been set by the internal `handleAttribute()` method are been rendered as so-called "pass-thru" attributes instead of that every single attribute of the component will be checked if it has been set or not, which may end up to be more expensive if there are relatively a lot of attributes. A "pass-thru" attribute is a component attribute which can just be outright rendered without any specific pre/postprocessing.

Peek around in Mojarra's [`RenderKitUtils`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-impl/2.0.0-RC/com/sun/faces/renderkit/RenderKitUtils.java) class, starting at the [`renderPassThruAttributes()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-impl/2.0.0-RC/com/sun/faces/renderkit/RenderKitUtils.java#302) method:

```
316         if (canBeOptimized(component, behaviors)) {
317             //noinspection unchecked
318             List<String> setAttributes = (List<String>)
319               component.getAttributes().get(ATTRIBUTES_THAT_ARE_SET_KEY);
320             if (setAttributes != null) {
321                 renderPassThruAttributesOptimized(context,
322                                                   writer,
323                                                   component,
324                                                   attributes,
325                                                   setAttributes,
326                                                   behaviors);
327             }
328         } else {
329 
330             // this block should only be hit by custom components leveraging
331             // the RI's rendering code, or in cases where we have behaviors
332             // attached to multiple events.  We make no assumptions and loop
333             // through
334             renderPassThruAttributesUnoptimized(context,
335                                                 writer,
336                                                 component,
337                                                 attributes,
338                                                 behaviors);
339         }
```

The `canBeOptimized()` returns `true` if the `component` is one of the standard JSF components (actually, if the component's package name starts with `javax.faces.component.`) and if there is no more than 1 behavior in the `behaviors` array.

The `renderPassThruAttributesOptimized()` will only render the attributes which are specified in `setAttributes` argument.

The `renderPassThruAttributesUnoptimized()` will loop through every single attribute in the `attributes` map and check for every single attribute if the associated value is not null/empty and then render it.

---

As to why some attributes are not been set by `handleAttribute()`, that's because they require some more specific pre/postprocessing and are already explicitly been rendered by the renderer specific to the component, so they don't need to be rendered as a "pass-thru" attribute.

---

You don't need to worry about this when writing custom components. You can always introduce your own optimizations similar to this, but it isn't recommend to rely on Mojarra-specific internal optimizations as they may not work at all when you're using MyFaces, for example.

Comment: So let say that I have a `logicalId` attribute that if this `logicalId` set, I will have it as the `id` instead of create a generic id for it, so according to what you said, this attribute does not need to call `handleAttribute` because it being process by my renderer. Whereas a `value` should be rendered as `pass-thru` attribute. Did I understand that correctly, BalusC?

Comment: Only if you're supplying *only* a custom renderer to an existing standard JSF component, or if you have your custom component in the `javax.faces.component` package and are utilizing Mojarra-specific helper classes/methods in your custom renderer.

Comment: By the way, the `value` attribute of `HtmlSelectOneRadio` (actually, `UIInput`) isn't been set by `handleAttribute()`. Perhaps that was just a bad example?

Comment: Sorry, I could not get back to you sooner. So any attributes of my custom component that I need to do something to it inside my custom renderer should not be a pass-thru attributes, is that right, BalusC? I asked these question because I saw PrimeFaces use this method on their SelectOneRadio component. They have `OPTIMIZED_PACKAGE = "org.primefaces.component."` and they call handleAttribute on `widgetVar`, and in their encode script, they do `writer.write("PrimeFaces.cw('SelectManyCheckbox','" + checkbox.resolveWidgetVar() + "',{");` Any idea why do want widgetVar a pass-thru attributes BalusC